Convergence in probability implies convergence in distribution. Proof verification
I have some doubts about my proof, I would be grateful if you can point any mistakes.
Statement:
Let $\{X_n\}$ converge to $X$ in probability. Show that $\{X_n\}$ converges to $X$ in distribution.
Proof:
As $\{X_n\}$ converges to $X$ in probability then for every continuous and bounded $f$, $\{f(X_n)\}$ converges to $f(X)$ in probability.
We need to show that $E f(X_n) \to E f(X)$ or $E f(X_n) - E f(X) = E (f(X_n) - f(X)) \to 0$.
Using the definition of expectation  $E (f(X_n) - f(X))  = 
\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} (f(x_n) - f(x)) f_{X_n, X}(x_n, x) \, \mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{d}x_n$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \ge N$, $P(|f(X_n)-f(X)|>\epsilon)<\delta$.
Now we can divide integral in two parts $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} (f(x_n) - f(x)) f_{X_n, X}(x_n, x) \, \mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{d}x_n = 
\int_{E} (f(x_n) - f(x)) f_{X_n, X}(x_n, x) \, \mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{d}x_n + \int_{\mathbb{R}^2\setminus E} (f(x_n) - f(x)) f_{X_n, X}(x_n, x) \, \mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{d}x_n$ where $E$ is a set on which $P(|f(X_n)-f(X)|>\epsilon)$ so the first integral can be bounded by $\epsilon \delta$ and the second by $M*P(E^c)$  where $M$ is some positive real number both of these quantities can be arbitrarily close to $0$.

Densities don't always exist.

You are right. Does $E (f(X_n)-f(X)) = \int_{\Omega} (f(X_n)-f(X))dP$ make sense?

Yes, that makes sense.

And if I substituted the integrals in my question by $\int_{E} (f(X_n)-f(X))dP$ and $\int_{\Omega \setminus E} (f(X_n)-f(X))dP$ would the proof be fine?

Yes, that would be a correct proof.

Thank you for help

Should $\epsilon$ and $M$ be swapped?

No, $f$ is a bounded function so $f(X_n)-f(X)$ is bounded too and $M$ is that bound.

You can shorten the proof a lot if you know this version of the Dominated Convergence Theorem: If $X_{n}\xrightarrow{P}X$ and $|X_{n}|\leq Y$ for all $n$ such that $E(Y)<\infty$, then $E(X_{n})\to E(X)$. Now see that $f(X_{n})\leq C$ as $f$ is a bounded continuous function and $f(X_{n})\to f(X)$ as $f$ is continuous. Apply the theorem above to complete the proof. Otherwise, one goes into a subsequential argument. Convergence in probability implies there is a subsequence along which you have almost sure convergence. So, you can apply the usual DCT in that case.

I know that you can prove it using Dominated Convergence Theorem but I wanted to use integrals as I struggle with them.

For any $c$ such that cdf of $X$ is continuous and for any $\epsilon>0$,
$$\begin{align}
P(X_n\leq c) &= P(X_n\leq c,\ X\leq c+\epsilon)+P(X_n\leq c,\ X>c+\epsilon),\\
P(X  \leq c) &= P(X_n\leq c,\ X\leq c-\epsilon)+P(X_n > c,\ X\leq c-\epsilon).\\
\end{align}$$
Thus, the absolute difference is
$$\begin{align}
&\left\lvert P(X_n\leq c) - P(X  \leq c) \right\rvert \\
\leq &\left\lvert P(X_n\leq c,\ X>c+\epsilon) - P(X_n > c,\ X\leq c+\epsilon) \right\rvert \\
&\quad+\left\lvert P(X_n\leq c,\ X\leq c+\epsilon) - P(X_n\leq c,\ X\leq c-\epsilon) \right\rvert\\
\leq &P(X_n\leq c,\ X>c+\epsilon) + P(X_n > c,\ X\leq c+\epsilon) \\
&\quad+P(X_n\leq c,\ c-\epsilon\leq X\leq c+\epsilon) \\
\leq&  P(X_n - X < -\epsilon) + P(X_n -X > \epsilon)+P( c-\epsilon\leq X\leq c+\epsilon)    \\
= &P\left(\left\lvert X_n-X\right\rvert >\epsilon \right)+P( c-\epsilon\leq X\leq c+\epsilon)  .
\end{align}$$
For fixed $\epsilon$, taking limit as $n\rightarrow0$,
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow0}\left\lvert P(X_n\leq c) - P(X  \leq c) \right\rvert \leq P( c-\epsilon\leq X\leq c+\epsilon),
$$
because $X_n\stackrel{p}{\longrightarrow} X$.
But $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary and the cdf of $X$ is continuous at $c$,
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow0}\left\lvert P(X_n\leq c) - P(X  \leq c) \right\rvert \leq \lim_{\epsilon\downarrow0}P( c-\epsilon\leq X\leq c+\epsilon) = 0.
$$

What exactly does your solution clarify in my proof? Or did you just post some different solution?

@Addy137 Kinda "standard" way of proving this. This one relies on probability only. So no need on explicit integration.
